# Server getting flodded with SPUCWorkerProcess.exe

Tags: 2010, sandbox-solution, timer-jobs

Got a SP2010 Server server that we use as an app server (not a WFE other than the Client Administrator). I had to reboot it to clear out dozens of processes as seen in Task Manager. We had probably 70+ instances each of: SPUCWorkerProcess.exe, SPUCWorkerProcessAlias.exe, and conhost.exe. Within a few business hours after reboot, there are already maybe 10 sets of those three processes piled up in the Task Manager, and the CPU is already floating between > 80-90%.

Googlebinging indicates the SPUC processes are related to sandboxed solutions. Thing is, we do not have a single sandboxed solution running on the farm. Are there other things that cause this, or masquerade as something else while in reality being a sandboxed solution? Example, we do have some sites built off of templates generated using "save site as template".

Possibly of value, this server runs the SharePoint 2010 Timer Service. We have found restarting the Timer service does alleviate the CPU max-out for a while, but that's obviously not a long-term solution. Worth mention, though.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Traverse all of your farm's site collections calling Get-SPUserSolution just to be 100% sure you don't have any hidden away sandbox solutions.

As for the web templates, dig deep around the functionality included in those templates. Think about how many you have and what those templates include.

Last, you should look at your resource points allocation for sandbox solutions. More information on that [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230316%28v=office.14%29.aspx).